# Yii how to interrupt data insert and logout instantly from the system

Tags: php, yii

What I want is that when a user submits a form (when clicked save), the system state should be checked and if it does not match, I need to interrupt data save and logout the user from the system. I tried this with `beforeSave()` and it works but the problem is that it does not work simultaneously.

i.e.- when the user click save button, data won't insert and when user clicks save button again
        then the user logs out from the system.

This is my current code:

```
//protected/model/supplier.php
class Supplier extends CActiveRecord{

     protected function beforeSave(){
            if(Yii::app()->params->SYSTEM_STATE==3){
                return false;
                Yii::app()->session->destroy();
                //Yii::app()->user->logout();
            }


            return parent::beforeSave();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about moving it to `beforeValidate()` ?

BTW change your code to

```
    if(Yii::app()->params->SYSTEM_STATE==3){
        Yii::app()->session->destroy();
        //Yii::app()->user->logout();
        return false;
    }
```

do the `return false` after all your code, not before

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I changed my code, but still the result is same.
changed code ::
      protected function beforeAction(){
            if(Yii::app()->params->SYSTEM_STATE==3){
                Yii::app()->user->logout();
                return false;
            }
            return parent::beforeAction($action);
        }

Answer (score 0):

In your example of code there is one logical issue. U first have 'return false;' line and second is 'Yii::app()->session->destroy();'.

Anyway, I think that best option for u to do this is in your controller action. Do something like this:

```
if (!$model->validate()) {
// your code for logout here
} else {
// continue with saving
}
```